# extract cab/zip file to destination computer via an MSI

Tags: windows-installer, wise

I have long hierarchy of source folder whose path length exceeds 255 character.

These are some demos and sample files that I have to deploy to the destination computer and they rarely changes (not seen them changes since past 2 years). Also we have loose uncompressed media for the MSI output.

Currently we are handling the long via filename:filename pair. I am wondering if I can zip all the content of the samples folder so It will be just one file and will be easy to maintain.

Problem is how can I extract this zip/cab file to destination computer at INSTALLDIR.

note: I cannot deploy 7zip or any open source extracters to destination computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have a .cab file you can use expand.exe. I'm not sure if it will handle the path length though, since it is still a windows tool.

Your other option is to write a c++/.NET custom action to unzip. In .NET it would be fairly trivial, as long as you have .NET 3.5 or higher. There are also some windows API's that allow you to do it.